# Combinatorics Database: Can I download all possible combinations for n choose k?

Tags: database, download, permutation, combinatorics

I am a researcher interested in combinatorics for experimental design.  I would like to easily be able to search the combinatorial space of some experimental materials for probabilistic features (i.e. n-gram probabilities for all possible combinations of K words chosen from N total possible words given a syllable alphabet A.)

I've tried generating my own lists using MATLAB but this takes way too long for all the conditions I would like to investigate.  Is anyone aware of a database that contains the lists for all possible combinations generated from n choose k?

In other words, is there a database that allows me to download all possible combinations of sequences of k items chosen from N total items?

Comment: IMHO, you're just doing it wrong.
When done right (implemented efficient algorithm in efficient language), generating all possible combinations k/N is much faster than downloading them.

Comment: I don't have much experience in efficient languages.. currently working on a implementation in python.  I can see how this database would be huge, perhaps I am overestimating compression technology.

Comment: Well, while python is not the fastest language, it will still give you good speed if algorithm is ok. Do you use some existing algorithm, or trying to write yourself?

Comment: I'm using the built-in itertools.combinations.  Having some issues with printing to files though since I am a pynub xD

Comment: finally got it working.. python is SO much faster than MATLAB x_x